# eclipse with moonrise color theme: change button color

Tags: eclipse, colors, ide, eclipse-kepler

I run the Eclipse Kepler IDE on redhat. I use the dark theme color Moonrise.

The buttons in all windows appear as white with white text. As you can imagine this is suboptimal...

How can I change the color of the buttons, or the color of the text buttons?

I looked into Preferences/Appearance/Colors and Fonts but could not find the correct color to change.

Here's how it looks:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a picture please? So we can see exactly what you mean. Also check that on General -> Appearance you have color and font theme setted as default (current) and the theme moonrise (standalone). It runs fine for me like that I just have the "Enable Animations" on the same tab  disabled.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added a pic and checked what you suggested. It is indeed the case.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer then.

Comment: I meant it is indeed the case that default (current) is selected, and moonrise standalone. But my problem is still there.

Comment: Ah! Ok, sorry about that. Have you tried making a" fresh install" of moonrise in another workspace? Might sound a bit "extreme" but maybe a fresh reinstall fix it up. Or... maybe is your redhat color/themes config that is screwing up eclipse buttons? Also I've migrated recently from Kepler to Mars using the same workspace and I'm using moonrise without any problems, just in case nothing works out with Kepler.

Comment: I've tried doing a reinstall, but it still does not work. In terms of the redhat color/theme config, how could I check if that's the issue? Do you know how to change it?  Regarding Eclipse's version, I have to stick with Kepler unfortunately,

Comment: I don't know were that option exactly is on redhat but I supose that as any other Linux distro you'll be able to change your Desktop theme preferences, like, Font color UI color etc. Just go there and play with the options and see if they affect Eclipse directly.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `SWT_GTK3=0` to the environment solved the problem.

So I create an eclipse_launcher file:

```
#!/bin/bash
export SWT_GTK3=0
/YOU/PATH/eclipse
```

Comment: Glad to see that you found the issue. Sorry that I couldn't help you out more.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem using the dark theme in Eclipse Neon in combination with the Flatabolous theme (http://www.noobslab.com/2016/07/flatabulous-theme-makes-your-desktop.html): all the buttons and text boxes had no contour, so they where merged with the background having the same color.

Elaborating on DevShark perfect answer (which made my day) I'll just add the eclipse.desktop launcher with this modification included which makes the contours visible:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Eclipse
GenericName=Eclipse IDE
Exec=bash -i -c "export SWT_GTK3=0 && /YOUR/PATH/eclipse"
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon=/YOUR/PATH/eclipse/icon.xpm
Comment=Integrated Development Environment
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Development;IDE;
Name[en]=Eclipse
```